# find solution of $\sum{\frac{1}{x_i-x}}=0$

Tags: calculus

Find $x$ that is a solution of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{x_i-x}}=0$.
I have no idea how to solve this problem. Taking gradient didn't help me also. Any hint?

Comment: You mean finding $x$ such that the function on the remaining n variables is identically zero? Or finding a particular solution for all those variables?

Comment: I mean, the former shouldn't be possible, but the later looks too vague, so not sure if you mean that or another thing.

Comment: I'm guessing OP wants to solve for $x$ in terms of $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

Comment: Will any $x$ do? $$\{ x_i + (-1)^k \; | 1 \leq k \leq n, \; k \in \mathbb{N} \; \}$$ is a trivial solution set. The sum becomes 1/1 + 1/-1 + 1/1 + 1/-1 + ...

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a general formula for $x$ as a function of the $x_i$. For any given collection of $x_i$, you can use Newton's Method to find arbitrarily accurate approximate solutions.

Comment: After making operations you have, for example with $n=3$,
$$\dfrac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{3-x}+\frac{1}{5-x}=-\frac{3x^2-18x+23}{x^3-9x^2+23x-15}=0$$ so you have to solve the equation $3x^2-18x+23=0$. But if you take more than three fractions you have to solve equations of $n-1$ degree and this you don't know how to do.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid confusion, I shall change notations.

You are looking for the zero's of function
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{1}{x-a_i}}$$ and they are $n$ solutions (one in each interval $(a_i,a_{i+1})$. The problem is that $f(x)$ is not very well conditioned because of these vertical asymptotes.

For a given interval, it is better to consider instead
$$g_k(x)=(x-a_k)(x-a_{k+1}) f(x)$$ which will write
$$g(x)=(x-a_k)(x-a_{k+1})\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}{\frac{1}{x-a_i}}+(2x-a_k-a_{k+1})+$$ $$(x-a_k)(x-a_{k+1})\sum_{i=k+2}^{n}{\frac{1}{x-a_i}}$$

Now, you see that
$$g(a_k)=a_k-a_{k+1} \qquad \text{and} \qquad  g(a_{k+1})=a_{k+1}-a_k$$ and the problem becomes simple. Use a combination of Newton and bisection steps (the lastest if Newton tends to take you out of the bounds).

May I confess that I spent decades working this type of equations ?

If you need more, just tell.